# Show that $f$ is Gateaux differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization, optimal-control

Define a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as follows
$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 
      \frac{2y \exp(-x^{-2})}{y^2+ \exp(-2x^{-2})} & x \neq 0 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise} 
   \end{cases}
$$
Show that $f$ is Gateaux differentiable at $(0,0)$ but that $f$ is not continuous there.
So I think I have to show that $f'((0,0),e_1)$ and $f'((0,0),e_2)$ exits and they are both linear. So far I have that $f'((0,0),e_1) =f'((0,0),e_2)=0$

Comment: Writing \exp rather than exp not only prevents italicization but also results in proper spacing in things like $a\exp b$, and is standard. (Similarly \sin, \log, \max, \sup, \det, etc.)  I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Along a curve where $x^2 = -1/\ln y$ for $0< x,y < 1$, we have $f(x,y) = 1$.  Hence $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.  The function is Gateaux differentiable if $\displaystyle \left.\frac{d}{d \epsilon}f(\epsilon h, \epsilon k)\right|_{\epsilon=0}$ exists for all $(h,k) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Note that in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ with $y < 1$ and $x^2 = -1/ \ln y$ we find

$$f(x,y) = \frac{2y\exp(-1/x^2)}{y^2 + \exp(-2/x^2)}= \frac{2y^2}{2y^2 }= 1,$$

and

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0);  x^2 = -1/ \ln y}f(x,y) = 1 \neq 0 = f(0,0)$$

Comment: But the curve doesn't contain (0,0)

Comment: @Timothy Brown:  The point is the limit of the function along that curve as you approach $(0,0)$ must be $1$ and does not equal $f(0,0) = 0$.  For $f$ to be continuous at a point the limit from any direction must equal the value  at the point.